# Add a close event button to every <li> in an <ul>

Tags: jquery

I would like to add an x button to every `<li>` I have in my `<ul>`.  This x (close) button will delete that individual `<li>` from the `<ul>`.  How do I do this using jQuery to create a single function that takes the `this` to delete the current item?

Heres my example HTML:

```
<ul id="list_a">
  <li value="1">Red&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>
  <li value="2">Orange&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>
  <li value="3">Green&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>
</ul>
```

edit: added close button `<span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Event delegation.](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)  Select the list, then ask it to listen to click events on the `.closeButton`s.  Then remove the `li` or the parent of the `span`.

```
$("#list_a").delegate(".closeButton", "click", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Why delegate? Just curious. This could be done as easily with traditional selection/binding.

Comment: `delegate` allows the OP to remove items added in the future.  `$("#list_a .closeButton").click( function(){...});` would work if nothing will ever be added.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Use live to bind click event to each element with closeButton class and remove it
$('.closeButton').live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});

<ul id="list_a">
   <li value="1">Red&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>
   <li value="2">Orange&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>
   <li value="3">Green&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="closeButton">X</span></li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gmcalab/zQmcn/9/)

Comment: this won't remove close button instead of li element

Comment: No it wasn't, the OP edited his answer, before it did not have the `<span class='closeButton'></span>` element. My original answer also removed `<li>`'s.

Answer (score 1):

I would also create the close Buttons dynamically with jQuery.

```
$('#list_a li').each(function(){
    $(this).append($('<span/>',{html:'X',class:'closeButton'}).click(function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }));
});
```